# How to add a hook to a macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, programming, expansion, hooks

LaTeX uses hooks extensively, one method employed is the command `g@addto@macro`. It is defined in source2e as:

```
 \long\def\g@addto@macro#1#2{%
  \begingroup
     \toks@\expandafter{#1#2}%
     \xdef#1{\the\toks@}%
  \endgroup}
```

I have used the `g@addto@macro` in the minimal example below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

\long\def\mainmacro{Preambles in main macro. \par}
\xdef\testOne{Contents of first macro. \par }
\xdef\testTwo{Contents of second macro. \par }

\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro{\mainmacro}{\testOne}
  \g@addto@macro{\mainmacro}{\testTwo \par}
  \g@addto@macro{\mainmacro}{Adhoc contents (1). \par}
  \g@addto@macro{\mainmacro}{\xdef\@elt{ Test } }
  \g@addto@macro{\mainmacro}{Adhoc contents (2).\@elt \par}
\makeatother

\mainmacro
\end{document}
```

What would be the best way to add a hook to the macro - at the beginning or for that matter anywhere but the end?

Comment: See [Patching Existing Commands](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/generic/FAQ-en/html/FAQ-patch.html) on the UK TeX FAQ.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: The link is dead now.

Comment: Sorry! here's a new link: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/latex/help/faq/uktug-faq/FAQ216.html

Comment: This question and answer is fairly out of date now that LaTeX has hook capabilities built in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\def\foo{\message{Here is the original \string\foo}}
\def\foohook{\message{Whatever.}}

% Add a hook to \foo (\foohook does not have be predefined):
\toks0\expandafter{\expandafter\foohook\foo}
\edef\foo{\the\toks0}

% Demo:
\foo
\def\foohook{\message{Redefined \string\foohook}}
\foo
\bye
```

(Complete working example; to turn it into latex, remove `\bye` and add necessary latex cruft.)

Comment: Thanks. Looks so much simpler than the LaTeX `@g@addto@macro`. TeX is fine too. For examples that don't use LaTeX packages I rather prefer TeX myself.

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package, which provides a rich set of commands for “hook management” and even “patching” of commands.