# Part numbering with suffixes: I, II, IIIa, IIIb, IV,

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, numbering, counters

I would like to have my parts numbered like this:

`I, II, IIIa, IIIb, ... , IV, ...`

I have written some code which works fine. But when using `hyperref`, I get this warning:
`destination with the same identifier (name{part.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`, because I reset the counter to zero for the sub-numbering.

### Question

Is there any way to achieve the same result, but without reseting the part counter (and without producing `hyperref`-warnings)?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\part{First}
\part{Second}

% change part numbering to ROMAN alph
\newcommand{\thelastpart}{\arabic{part}}%store old number
\edef\thelastpartexp{\thelastpart}
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\edef\themainpart{\thepart} 
\setcounter{part}{0}%set subcounter
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\themainpart\alph{part}}

\part{Third a}
\part{Third b}

% reset part numbering
\setcounter{part}{\thelastpartexp}%restore counter
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}


\part{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you can, I would look at writing something like a `\subpart` command to do this for you, and potentially not including it in the toc (or is the TOC a *necessary* feature?)

Comment: It has to be in the TOC, as the part is just "splitted into two"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make hyperref happy with your own solution it is enough to redefine `\theHpart` so that it gives unique values, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\part{First}
\part{Second}

% change part numbering to ROMAN alph
\newcommand{\thelastpart}{\arabic{part}}%store old number
\edef\thelastpartexp{\thelastpart}
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\edef\themainpart{\thepart}
\setcounter{part}{0}%set subcounter
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\themainpart\alph{part}}
\renewcommand{\theHpart}{\themainpart\alph{part}}%<--------------

\part{Third a}
\part{Third b}

% reset part numbering
\setcounter{part}{\thelastpartexp}%restore counter
\addtocounter{part}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}
\renewcommand{\theHpart}{\Roman{part}} %<--(probably not really needed)

\part{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Very simple and impressive. Thank you, learned a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution inspired by `subequation`. You use the command `\Part` that takes an optional argument in which you can specify the `subpart` option for those parts you want to share the main number. You can also specify `toctitle=...` for a different title that should go in the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Part}{ O{} m }
 {
  \ralfix_part:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\keys_define:nn { ralfix/part }
 {
  toctitle .tl_set:N = \l_ralfix_toctitle_tl,
  subpart .bool_set:N = \l_ralfix_subpart_bool,
  subpart .default:n = { true },
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ralfix_part:nn #1 #2
 {
  \keys_set:nn { ralfix/part }
   {
    subpart=false,
    toctitle=#2,
    #1
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_ralfix_subpart_bool
   {
    \int_compare:nT { \value{subpart} = 0 }
     {
      \stepcounter{part}
      \cs_gset:Npx \thepart { \thepart \exp_not:N \alph{subpart} }
      \cs_gset_eq:cc { c@part } { c@subpart }
     }
   }
   {
    \cs_gset_eq:cN { c@part } \ralfix_part_counter:
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \thepart \ralfix_part_thepart:
    \int_compare:nT { \value{subpart}=1 }
     {
      \use:c { @latex@warning@no@line }
       { You~had~only~one~subpart~%
         \int_to_Roman:n {\value{part}-1},~%
         check~your~input }
     }
    \setcounter{subpart}{0}
   }
  \stepcounter{Hpart} % keep hyperref happy
  \part[\l_ralfix_toctitle_tl]{#2}
 }

\cs_set_eq:Nc \ralfix_part_counter: { c@part }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ralfix_part_thepart: \thepart
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcounter{Hpart}
\newcounter{subpart}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\pagebreak

\Part{First}
\Part{Second}

\Part[subpart]{Third a}
\Part[subpart,toctitle=Third toc b]{Third b}

\Part{Fourth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: added a warning if there's a single subpart.

Comment: This is really nice, but "heavy"... Thank you for providing (another) `xparse`-solution, I learn a lot from your answers.

Comment: @ralfix If you look closely, it's not very different in implementation from Ulrike's, but it spares you from complicated code in the body of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a whole other sectioning command, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\formatsubparthead}{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\formatsubparttext}{\Large\bfseries}

\newcounter{subpart}[part]
\newcommand{\subpart}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{subpart}{1}%
  \vspace*{1em}\noindent %
  {\formatsubparthead Part \Roman{part}\alph{subpart}}%
  \par\vspace*{1em}
  {\formatsubparttext #1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\Roman{part}\alph{subpart}\quad #1}%
  \par\vspace*{2em}\noindent%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part One}
\subpart{Something}
\lipsum[1]
\subpart{Something Else}
\lipsum[2]
\part{Part Two}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Real quick: Just in case Part II (and any later parts) also feature subparts, you should modify the `\part` command so that the `subpart` counter is reset to `0` automatically.

Comment: Edited, thanks for that.  (Although there is a [smarter way](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/how-to-add-a-hook-to-a-macro) that I can't get working.)

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcounter{subpart}[part]` be easier to let the subpart counter reset at new parts?

Comment: I need the splitted part to look exactly like the non-splitted ones, so this is not the solution I am looking for... Thank you!

Comment: @ralfix Fair enough.